# performance issues, delay while loading the forms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing a web application in VS 2010. My application has more than 180 forms and immense amount of controls on each form. I would like to know , if the application is hosted , will there be any performance issues, delay while loading the forms, or any other issues? please advice and suggestions if any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are worried or not sure, why don't you test it?

Answer (score 1):

1. The thing you need to check is memory on the server machine i.e ram
   and cpu processing power
2. You need to do code review  for the viewsate of each page, javascript, css if something is not needed remove it asap.
3. check for the server side also for the Session state and Caching management.

other points are

1. ASP.NET pipeline optimization
2. ASP.NET process configuration optimization
3. Things you must do for ASP.NET before going live
4. Content Delivery Network
5. Caching AJAX calls on browser
6. aking best use of Browser Cache
7. On demand progressive UI loading for fast smooth experience
8. Optimize ASP.NET 2.0 Profile provider
9. How to query ASP.NET 2.0 Membership tables without bringing down the site
10. Prevent Denial of Service (DOS) attack

Check full article : [10 ASP.NET Performance and Scalability Secrets](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/10ASPNetPerformance.aspx)

.

Answer (score 0):

My friend, use a profiler. It's the most accurate means of determining where the bottleneck in your application is.

A search for [asp.net profiler](http://www.google.com.ph/search?q=asp.net+profiler) will provide free tools that you can use.